# Issue selecting inputs inside TD tags

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a html like:

```
<table id="table1">  
  <tr>  
    <td>TEXT</td>  
    <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>  
    <td><input type="number" value="2"></td>  
    <td><input type="button" class="go" value="go"></td>  
  </tr>  
  <tr>  
    <!-- same structure above -->  
  </tr>  
</table>
```

and I'm trying to target the inputs (type number), with Jquery.

I've tried two approaches:

#1:

```
$('#table1').on('click', '.go', function(){
  var faixa = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
  p = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input:first').val();
  g = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input:nth-child(2)').val();
});
```

and #2:

```
$('#table1').on('click', '.go', function(){
  var faixa = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
  p = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2) input').val();
  g = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(3) input').val();
});
```

In the first one, the value of 'g' is undefined ('p' is correct) and in the second one, 'p' is undefined ('g' is correct).

Can someone explain me why this is happening and I cannot get the right value for both variables? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth-child` basically means to find the `nth-child` in each qualifying matching criteria. Since you have `find('td input:nth-child(2)')` , which would mean that find the 2nd input occurrence in each `td`. Since each `td` only has 1 input, if would give you `undefined`.

I would recommend using `.eq()` selector which starts from zeroth index.

```
$('#table1').on('click', '.go', function(){
  var faixa = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
  p = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input:first').val();
  g = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input').eq(1).val();
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/s51sayvc/1/

or

```
$('#table1').on('click', '.go', function(){
  var faixa = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
  p = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input:first').val();
  g = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(2).find('input').val();
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/s51sayvc/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector like following.

```js
$('#table1').on('click', '.go', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var faixa = tr.find('td:first').text(),
    p = tr.find('td input:eq(0)').val(),
    g = tr.find('td input:eq(1)').val();

    console.log(faixa, p, g);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>TEXT</td>
        <td><input type="number" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="go" value="go"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**:nth-child()** is counting elements from 0, so to get first element you have to type: **:nth-child(0)** (so it's the same as :first), for second element: **:nth-child(1)**.

So the first approach would work fine with code:

```
$('#table1').on('click', '.go', function(){
  var faixa = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
  p = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input:first').val();
  g = $(this).closest('tr').find('td input:nth-child(1)').val(); 
});
```

And for the second approach, it should look like that:

```
$('#table1').on('click', '.go', function(){
  var faixa = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
  p = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(0) input').val();
  g = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1) input').val();
});
```